# Add dependencies for my Rcpp package

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

Rcpp beginner's question:

I want to improve my execution efficiency in R. So I write some code in cpp and use Rcpp to help me compile them.

Question is that I use some other R packages in my .cpp files and I want those packages to be installed and imported automatically when a user installs my package.

e.g.  If I use the R package 'gtools' in my files, I don't want the error:

```
* installing to library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/library'
* installing *source* package 'pkgname' ...
make: Nothing to be done for `all`.
** libs
installing to C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/library/pkgname/libs/i386
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in library(gtools) : there is no package called 'gtools'
Error : unable to load R code in package 'pkgname'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'pkgname'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/library/pkgname'

Exited with status 1.
```

I tried to add depended package name to the **DESCRIPTION** file. i.e.

```
Imports: Rcpp (>= 0.12.12),gtools
LinkingTo: Rcpp, gtools
```

But it gives me following error:

```
ERROR: dependency 'gtools' is not available for package 'pkgname'
```

I don't find any similar questions and please tell me if there are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should probably make sure `gtools` is *installed* on your system. I say this because of the following error:

> Error in library(gtools) : there is no package called 'gtools'

With this being said, the main issue you are running into is uncertainty between the `LinkingTo:` and `Imports:` fields in the `DESCRIPTION` file. This is covered in [Section 1.1.3: Package Dependencies](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies) of [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html).

Specifically, we have:

> The `‘Imports’` field lists packages whose namespaces are imported from (as specified in the `NAMESPACE` file) but which do not need to be attached. Namespaces accessed by the `‘::’` and `‘:::’` operators must be listed here, or in `‘Suggests’` or `‘Enhances’` (see below). Ideally this field will include all the standard packages that are used, and it is important to include S4-using packages (as their class definitions can change and the `DESCRIPTION` file is used to decide which packages to re-install when this happens). Packages declared in the `‘Depends’` field should not also be in the `‘Imports’` field. Version requirements can be specified and are checked when the namespace is loaded (since R >= 3.0.0).

And the `LinkingTo` field:

> A package that wishes to make use of header files in other packages needs to 
>   declare them as a comma-separated list in the field `‘LinkingTo’` in the 
>   `DESCRIPTION` file. For example
>
> ```
> LinkingTo: link1, link2
> ```
>
> The `‘LinkingTo’` field can have a version requirement which is checked at installation.
>
> Specifying a package in ‘LinkingTo’ suffices if these are C++ headers containing source code or static linking is done at installation: the packages do not need to be (and usually should not be) listed in the ‘Depends’ or `‘Imports’` fields. This includes CRAN package [`BH`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=BH) and almost all users of [`RcppArmadillo`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppArmadillo) and [`RcppEigen`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppEigen).
>
> For another use of `‘LinkingTo’` see [Linking to native routines in other packages](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Linking-to-native-routines-in-other-packages).

So, the **`Imports:`** is meant to specify packages that contain *R* functions that you wish to import. In particular, the function from a given package or the entire package itself must be specified in the `NAMESPACE` file. For packages that use *Rcpp*, you can typically expect *R* functions to be available if the author has exported the routine from C++.

Now, regarding the **`LinkingTo:`**, this is a bit more specific. If an author wishes to make available a *C++* API via header files they must explicitly declare the statements as is given in *[native methods](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Linking-to-native-routines-in-other-packages)* of [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html). Generally, packages that proceed in this manner are "header-only". These packages place the header definitions under `inst/include`, e.g.

```
|- pkgname
   |- inst/
      |- include/
         |- pkgname.h
   |- R/
   |- man/
   |- DESCRIPTION
   |- NAMESPACE
```

However, another trend is to allow for "non-header" packages. This leads to a bit more complicated of topic as you have to understand shared objects and dynamic libraries. CRAN presents an overview of *how to "Link" packages* in [Section 5.8: Linking to other packages](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Linking-to-other-packages) of [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html)

If the author does *not* make available a C++ API, then there are *four* options:

1. Ask the *author* nicely to support calling the *C++* API or submit a patch that enables access to the *C++* API.
2. [Call an *R* function from *C++*](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/r-function-from-c++/). (This negates any performance gain from writing your code in *C++* though.)
3. Copy the implementation from the author's package while respecting their intellectual property.
4. Implement the desired functionality from scratch to avoid licensing issues.

Unfortunately, this is the case for `gtools`. As the author(s) [do not provide a means to "link" to the *C++* version of package's code](https://github.com/cran/gtools/tree/a62d2b0a1f007063780bae7617baa74b1d9db79c/inst).